# change value to other value and the "!" operator

Tags: javascript, react-native

so by the logic in my head:

if I touch the opacity of Email then globlas.Email should change from false to true but in fact it does nothing

because I think when 'this.getMedia(item.MediaNow)' = true
then musst be:   '!(!this.getMedia(item.MediaNow))' = false

could someone please explain me why?
or maybe tel me how to make my code work like I intend.

```
getMedia = Media => {
 switch (Media) {
   case "Call":
    return global.Call;
  case "Email":
    return global.Email;


setMedia = (Media, value) => {
 switch (Media) {
  case "Call":
    global.Call = value;
    this.setState({});

  case "Email":
    global.Email= value;
    this.setState({});


 {...}


 <TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
   this.setMedia(!this.getMedia(item.MediaNow)); 
// MediaNow is either "Call" or "Email". so my expectet result of 
// (!this.getMedia(item.MediaNow)) would be: true/false

  }}
 >
```

#### global.js:

```
export default {
 Call: false,
 Email: false,
};
```

#### Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: setMedia expects 2 arguments and you pass in one....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your method:

```
setMedia = (Media, value) => {
```

Now look at how you are calling it

```
this.setMedia(!this.getMedia(item.MediaNow));
```

Methods expects two arguments and you are passing it one.

```
this.setMedia(item.MediaNow, !this.getMedia(item.MediaNow));
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you're returning a value defined inside the global object.

When using the ! operator, JavaScript will try to convert that value to a boolean and subsequently will apply the negation.

In your case 
`!this.getMedia(item.MediaNow)`

Will be parsed as ...give me the value of `this.getMedia(item.MediaNow)` and convert it to bool.

JS will check if the value is falsy (undefined, zero, false, etc) or true (object, non empty string, etc).

In your case...
!`(something true) == false`